# documents are not printing in sequence in java

Tags: java, printing

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< letters.size(); i++){
    Map<String,Object> letter= letters.get(i);
    String path      = letter.get("path").toString();
    File pritingFile = new File(path);   
    Desktop desktop = null;
       if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    desktop.print(pritingFile); 
        }

  }
```

above for loop is printing around 200 letters but the printer is not printing letters in the sequence of order which is sent to print.

Comment: `Desktop desktop = null;
       if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {` this will lead to NPE.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc why would a static method call lead to NPE?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, oh it is a static method. In this case there is no `NPE`. If it was an instance method it would cause an NPE

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for `print(...)` says:

> Prints a file with the native desktop printing facility, using the associated application's print command.

There are no guarantees about the order in which files are printed by the native (i.e. OS) print system.  Indeed, the javadoc doesn't even state that the formatted document has been submitted to the printer queue by the time that `print` returns.

You may have more success using the javax.print API:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html

There is an example in the above page.